# Laravel Passport: Provider for API Guard returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have an API using Laravel 5.7 and Passport. I'm trying to get the User Provider from the Guard when calling the API but it's returning null ONLY for the API Guard.

When I use dd(auth()) I get the following:

```
#guards: array:2 [▼
    "web" => SessionGuard {#489 ▼
      #name: "web"
      #lastAttempted: null
      #viaRemember: false
      #session: Store {#492 ▶}
      #cookie: CookieJar {#493 ▶}
      #request: Request {#55 ▶}
      #events: Dispatcher {#35 ▶}
      #loggedOut: false
      #recallAttempted: false
      #user: null
      #provider: EloquentUserProvider {#483 ▼
        #hasher: HashManager {#488 ▶}
        #model: "App\User"
      }
    }
    "api" => RequestGuard {#526 ▼
      #callback: Closure {#527 ▶}
      #request: Request {#55 ▶}
      #user: User {#655 ▶}
      #provider: null
    }
]
```

On my config/auth.php file:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Is there any other configuration I have to set to make this work?